Lack of libraries in textattack.augmentation
I am trying to augment my text data using textattack.augmentation (running on Kaggle).
The error is ImportError: cannot import name 'IdentityCache' from 'botocore.utils' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/utils.py) 
I have found a solution for this on another stack overflow question. But it doesn't work, and I can see 4 downvoted.
So I expect some solutions can deal with this problem.
Furthermore, are there any augmentation methods with high speed and performance?Thank!

Check your both botocore and boto3 are updated to the latest versions.
Some release of boto3 can have some issues , try to use specefic version
!pip install botocore==x.xx.x boto3==x.xx.x
check this for more details boto3
Part 2
you can use WordNetAugmenter() for synonym replacement
For Random,
you can use RandomInsertionAugmenter() for random insetion
RandomSwapAugmenter() use for random swap
RandomDeletionAugmenter() can be use for random deletion
For Back translation -> BackTranslationAugmenter()
In the textattack
there are more you can go through the documentions

Thank you for your help, but it actually doesn't solve the problem.
The error keep ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore.compress'

Thank you for your help, but it actually doesn't solve the problem.
The error keep ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore.compress'
